# Computer won't restart without recovery mode and mouse is flickering after I added the ppa ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

Tags: ubuntu, video, elementary-os

I installed Steam a few weeks ago, and it kept bothering me to add the ppa `ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`,so I did it yesterday. After I installed it, my computer was fine until I rebooted. The computer wouldn't boot, it just froze on the splash screen of Elementary OS.

In the recovery mode, I did '`ppa-purge ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`', and then booted from the recovery mode, and it went fine.

But now I can only boot from recovery mode, else it will just freeze on the splash screen, the problem is that after I boot, my cursor disappears when not moving, and flickers while moving.

How can I fix that? Do I have to reinstall the system?
**Edit:**
I just noticed that Gala(elementary OS's window manager) is constantly at 200%+ CPU usage, and there are other instances of it with 20~40% of usage.Not shure if it is related.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing AMD graphic drivers, whch were probably installed by that ppa(I also purged that ppa).

Comment: It was working for a few days, when I reply talking about it  it stops working, my mouse is flickering again (lol).